# canOpenURL: without using LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Tags: ios, lsapplicationqueriesschemes

I'm calling `canOpenURL:` without `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in my `Info.plist`, yet this call returns true:

> BOOL canMakePhoneCalls = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
> canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:+123"]];

1. If I use a different URL (e.g., "https://..." or even @"xxxxxxxxtel:+123"), `canOpenURL:` returns false, as expected.
2. if I add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` to my `Info.plist` but with an empty list of schemes, the above code still returns true.
3. Worse, if I specify "https" as one of the schemes, `canOpenURL:` with an https URL still returns false.

My deployment target is iOS 12 (specifically, long after iOS 9).

I'm expecting `canOpenURL:` to always return false since `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` is missing.  Why is it (1) returning true for the telephone scheme when `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` is missing, and (2) not returning true when I specify "https" in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`?

(This might not mean anything, but Xcode doesn't show a readable text string for `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` when "Raw Keys & Values" is off -- it still shows "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes".)

Comment: You don't need to specify `tel` in your query scheme nor https. The point of the plist key was to crack down on apps that were building an "app inventory" by probing for URL schemes. Querying for `tel` doesn't tell you anything about the user's apps. You can always assume that `https` urls are available.

Comment: @Paulw11 Apple's docs are very clear that the key is required for `canOpenURL:` to work, regardless of the scheme, although my tests show that `tel` works without the key.  But, I cannot get `https` to work (`canOpenURL:` returns false).  Where do you find docs saying that `tel` and `https` are allowed without the key?

Comment: Observation and Experience. You've proven it for yourself. Understanding that the background to the queriesScheme key is privacy you can see how it isn't required for tel or https.  You could submit a bug to apple regarding the behaviour I guess.